# The argument width of pygame.draw.rect() fills a rect problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm struggling with `pygame.draw.rect()`. My goal is to make outline(border line) of a rectangle appear.

#### Issue

I put a text:

- `text_surf = test_font.render('Rect Test', False, 'black')`
- `screen.blit(text_surf, text_rect)`

I put a pink rectangle under the text:

- `text_rect = text_surf.get_rect(center=(400, 100))`
- `pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'pink', text_rect)`

Last, put another rectangle under the previous one, and used width argument to make green outline:

- `pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'green', text_rect, 50)`

I ran my code. I only saw a text and a green rectangle (not green outline)

#### What I tried

- I wrote an argument name `width` to specify what the int is for.

  - `pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'green', text_rect, width=50)` -> didn't work
- I changed the order of code for the rectangles. -> didn't work

  - I could only saw a text and a pink rectangle

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'pink', text_rect)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'green', text_rect, 50)
screen.blit(text_surf, text_rect)

# Change order -> didn't work!
pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'green', text_rect, 50)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'pink', text_rect)
screen.blit(text_surf, text_rect)
```

How can I make outline appear?

#### My code

```py
from cgitb import text
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption('Rect Test')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
test_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)

# Text and rectangle
text_surf = test_font.render('Rect Test', False, 'black')
text_rect = text_surf.get_rect(center=(400, 100))


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'pink', text_rect)

    # I want to make a border line but it fills the rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'green', text_rect, 50)
    screen.blit(text_surf, text_rect)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

What I want
[image: What I want]

What I got
[image: What I got]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified the width of the border rect to be fifty pixels. From your desired image, it seems like that is not correct.

It also seems like you want the border to be larger than the text rect, there's a neat method that helps you [resize rects](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate):

```
border_rect = text_rect.inflate(5,5)
```

Then you draw the border with a width of five:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'green', border_rect, width=5)
```

This will show:

[image: Bordered text]

Comment: Thank you so so much! It worked!! By the way, I was coding following a lesson video. The code I post worked on the lecturer's pc without using `.inflate()`. My computer is Mac, and I guess his is Windows. Could the difference cause the problem? I am wondering why the code doesn't work on my computer...

Comment: @Miu I expect that your lecturer had a smaller border, maybe one or two pixels so it didn't overlap the text much without `inflate()`-ing the rect.